# Group Django model objects to a distinct column

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following Django model

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I want to create a query/multiple queries which will group all the TestModel objects to the particular `company_name`. In a nutshell it will have the following structure.

```
out - {
    "company_name_test_1": [TestModel1, TestModel2, TestModel3],
    "company_name_test_2": [TestModel4, TestModel5, TestModel6],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
companyNames = ["a", "b", "c"]

result = {}

for name in companyNames:
    result[name] = list(TestModel.objects.filter(company_name = name))
```

If you want to save the dictionary as JSON or something similar, the filtered models will need to be serialised first.

Also, depending on the logic of your program, it might be worth having a 'company' model, and having the TestModels as a foreign key to their respective companies.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    # other fields and functions

class TestModel(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then you can just filter by foreign key to get the company's testmodels:

```
results = {}

for company in Company.objects.all():
    results[company.name] = list(company.testmodel_set.all())
```